# Summation of Gamma functions and fractions

Tags: summation, gamma-function

Can anyone explain to me what identities are used to get the solution:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n} \frac{\Gamma(t+a)}{\Gamma{(t)}}=\frac{n\Gamma(a+n+1)}{(a+1)\Gamma{(n+1)}}$$

This is only the last step of a much longer problem I was assigned, and since I have never covered identities of Gamma functions I am not sure how to show this is correct!

I am willing to upload the whole question if it is required.

Comment: `\gamma`=$\gamma$ while `\Gamma`=$\Gamma$. For more, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Comment: @anon can you help me prove why this equality is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the only identity you need is

$$\Gamma(t+1) = t \cdot \Gamma(t)$$

Also, it helps to know that you can work out the value of $\Gamma$ for integers with the formula (which follows by induction from the above and from $\Gamma(1)=1$):

$$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$$

Working out your problem: For $n=1$, the left hand side is

$$\frac {\Gamma(1+a)} {\Gamma(1)} =\frac {\Gamma(1+a)} {1}= \Gamma(1+a)$$

and the right hand side is

$$\frac {\Gamma(a+2)} {(a+1)\Gamma(2)}$$

Using the identity I mentioned in the beginning, this reduces to

$$\frac {\Gamma(a+2)} {(a+1)\Gamma(2)} = \frac {(a+1)\Gamma(a+1)} {(a+1)\cdot 1} = \Gamma(1+a)$$

You can work the rest by induction on $n$.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! How would you takle the problem if you did not have the solution already? Because I found the solution by using a program, so I have to mathematically show how I got it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're given only the left hand side and want to find a formula for it? I would plug in, let's say, $n=3$ to get a sum of 3 things. Now, using the valuable recurrence formula $\Gamma(t+1) = t\cdot\Gamma(t)$, reduce the appearances of $\Gamma$ in the 3 summands so that they show just $\Gamma(a+4)$ and $\Gamma(4)$ everywhere. Add up and see what you get. Conjecture the general case, and prove by induction.